# Class doesn't fetch correctly the object's values

Tags: php, oop

Given this class :

```
class Address {
  public $id;
  public $id_easypost;
  public $street1;
  public $street2;

  public function __construct($id,$id_easypost,$street1,$street2) {
      $this->$id = $id;
      $this->$id_easypost = $id_easypost;
      $this->$street1 = $street1;
      $this->$street2 = $street2;
  }
}
```

I don't get why, when creating an object like that:

```
$ad = new Address("1", "2", "3", "4");
```

Values are not "fetched" correctly :

```
 object(Address)[15]
  public 'id' => null
  public 'id_easypost' => null
  public 'street1' => null
  public 'street2' => null
  public '1' => string '1' (length=1)
  public '2' => string '2' (length=1)
  public '3' => string '3' (length=1)
  public '4' => string '4' (length=1)
```

However, this class works correctly :

```
class Rider {
  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $activated;
  public $created_at;
  public $updated_at;

  public function __construct($id, $name, $activated, $created_at, $updated_at) {
    $this->id        = $id;
    $this->name       = $name;
    $this->activated = $activated;
    $this->created_at = $created_at;
    $this->updated_at = $updated_at;
  }
}
```

And "fetch" the values correctly.

```
object(Rider)[16]
  public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'name' => string '2' (length=1)
  public 'activated' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 'created_at' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'updated_at' => string '5' (length=1)
```

How is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `$` sign to access object properties. This is correct:

```
 $this->id = $id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was simply a typo ! Extra question : what does the number in object(Address)[15] or object(Rider)[16] means ?